# How to use scanf in a loop to get a char* array in c

Tags: c, arrays, char, newline, scanf

I want to get a `char` array values using `scanf`. I used this code:

```
    // get first array
    printf("first length:\n");
    scanf("%d", &f_l);
    printf("first number:\n");
    for(i=0 ; i<=f_l ; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &first[i]);
    }
    //start test
    printf("first number is:\n");
    for(i=0 ; i<=LEN ; i++) {
        printf("(%c | %d)", first[i],i);
    }
```

but when I print the array, I found a `\n` in the first place (`first[0]`), and the other chars starts from `place[1]` instead! why is that, and how to fix it?

Comment: `i<=f_l` --> `i<f_l`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY In general, you're very right, but `f_l` is user supplied and _maybe_ OP wants _that_ length, who knows. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because a `'\n'` is left in the buffer when you do `scanf()` for `f_l`.

Use a trailing space, it should work

```
for(i=0 ; i<=f_l ; i++) {
    scanf(" %c", &first[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Atheel Alongwith saying "thanks", you can consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) an answer that helped you. :)

Comment: the both answers are correct. How to choose one :) ?

Answer (score 3):

In your code,

```
scanf("%c", &first[i]);
```

reads and stores the previously entered newline (`\n`) character. You need to change

```
scanf("%c", &first[i]);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &first[i]);
       ^
       |
```

to avoid the previously entered newline (`\n`) character generated from previous <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press. The leading space before the `%c` will cause the `scanf()` to *ignore* any number of leading whitespace character (including a newline) and read the first non-whitespace character (expected input).

That said, directly using a user-supplied value for array indexing against a predefined array can be problematic. At Least, have a check for the user- entered value being less than the defined array size.